# Is there a quick way in R to predict the class outcome of an observation from a nearest neighbours model from RANN?

Tags: r, performance, classification, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to identify the most probable group that an observation belongs to, for several thousand large datasets. It is possible that some of the data is incorrectly classified and I am trying to work out the most likely "true" value. I have tried to use `knn3` from the `caret` package but the predictions take too long to compute. In researching alternatives I have came across the `nn2` function from `RANN` package which performs a nearest neighbour search that is significantly faster than K-Nearest Neighbours.

```
library(RANN)
library(tidyverse)

iris.scaled <- iris %>% 
    mutate_if(is.numeric, scale)

iris.nn2 <- nn2(iris.scaled[1:4])
```

The result on the `nn2` function is two lists, one of indices and one of distances. I want to use the indices table to work out the most likely grouping of each observation, however it returns the row number of the observation and not it's group. I need to replace this with the group it belongs to (in this case, the species column).

```
distance.index <- iris.nn2$nn.idx[,-1]
target = iris.scaled$Species
```

I have removed the first column as the first nearest neighbour is always the observation itself.

```
matrix(target[distance.index[,]], nrow = nrow(distance.index), ncol = ncol(distance.index))
```

This code gives me the output I want, but is there a tidier way of creating this table and then calculating the most common response for each row, with the speed of calculation being the key.

Comment: I deleted a response of mine because I realized it was basically the same as your `matrix()` call (which I expect to be very fast). However, note the following: "I have removed the first column as the first nearest neighbour is always the observation itself." - I recently found out that this need not be the case and you should not rely a this. If one element is "the same" as another element, it may not be the nearest neighbour to itself. Thus, you may need to ensure that no row in distance.index contains the row index, and not just remove the first row!

Comment: To get the most frequent category per row, you can use `apply(category_neighbours, 1, function(x) as.numeric(names(sort(table(x)))[1]))`, but I do not know if this is as speedy as you would like, given it used a row-wise `apply()` operation.

Answer (score 0):

Your scaling can be a real bottleneck when you have more columns (tested on 200 x 22216 gene expression matrix). My version might not seem that impressive with the `iris` dataset, but on the larger dataset I get 1.3 sec vs. 32.8 sec execution time.

Using `tabulate` instead of `table` gives an additional improvement, which is dwarfed, however, by the matrix scaling.

I used a custom scale function here, but using `base::scale` on a matrix would already be a major improvement.

I also addressed the issue raised by M. Papenberg of "self" not being considered the nearest neighbor by setting those to NA.

```r
invisible(lapply(c("tidyverse", "matrixStats", "RANN", "microbenchmark", "compiler"), 
    require, character.only=TRUE))

enableJIT(3)

# faster column scaling (modified from https://www.r-bloggers.com/author/strictlystat/)
colScale <- function(x, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE, rows = NULL, cols = NULL) {
    if (!is.null(rows) && !is.null(cols)) {x <- x[rows, cols, drop = FALSE]
    } else if (!is.null(rows)) {x <- x[rows, , drop = FALSE]
    } else if (!is.null(cols)) x <- x[, cols, drop = FALSE]
    cm <- colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    if (scale) csd <- matrixStats::colSds(x, center = cm, na.rm = TRUE) else
        csd <- rep(1, length = length(cm))
    if (!center) cm <- rep(0, length = length(cm))
    x <- t((t(x) - cm) / csd)
    return(x)
}

# your posted version (mostly):
oldv <- function(){
    iris.scaled <- iris %>% 
        mutate_if(is.numeric, scale)
    iris.nn2 <- nn2(iris.scaled[1:4])
    distance.index <- iris.nn2$nn.idx[,-1]
    target = iris.scaled$Species
    category_neighbours <- matrix(target[distance.index[,]], nrow = nrow(distance.index), ncol = ncol(distance.index))
    class <- apply(category_neighbours, 1, function(x) {
        x1 <- table(x)
        names(x1)[which.max(x1)]})
    cbind(iris, class)
}

## my version:
myv <- function(){
    iris.scaled <- colScale(data.matrix(iris[, 1:(dim(iris)[2]-1)]))
    iris.nn2 <- nn2(iris.scaled)

    # set self neighbors to NA
    iris.nn2$nn.idx[iris.nn2$nn.idx - seq_len(dim(iris.nn2$nn.idx)[1]) == 0] <- NA

    # match up categories
    category_neighbours <- matrix(iris$Species[iris.nn2$nn.idx[,]],
        nrow = dim(iris.nn2$nn.idx)[1], ncol = dim(iris.nn2$nn.idx)[2])

    # turn category_neighbours into numeric for tabulate
    cn <- matrix(as.numeric(factor(category_neighbours, exclude=NULL)),
        nrow = dim(iris.nn2$nn.idx)[1], ncol = dim(iris.nn2$nn.idx)[2])
    cnl <- levels(factor(category_neighbours, exclude = NULL))

    # tabulate frequencies and match up with factor levels
    class <- apply(cn, 1, function(x) {
        cnl[which.max(tabulate(x, nbins=length(cnl))[!is.na(cnl)])]})
    cbind(iris, class)
}

microbenchmark(oldv(), myv(), times=100L)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
#>  oldv() 11.015986 11.679337 12.806252 12.064935 12.745082 33.89201   100   b
#>   myv()  2.430544  2.551342  3.020262  2.612714  2.691179 22.41435   100  a
```